# Copy file if USB storage is plugged in by batch file. Windows CE 6.0

Tags: batch-file, copy, windows-ce, usb-drive

**Environment**

A machine with an HMI running Windows CE 6.0. The user is never seeing the Windows environment or a file Explorer.

**Task**

I would like to copy a file onto a USB stick using a batch file.

**Issue**

If the USB stick isn't plugged in when the user runs the batch file, `copy` will create a file called `USB Storage` and when the USB stick is then being plugged in it will be called `USB Storage2`. Unlike `xcopy` which is in CE not available `copy` does not take any arguments except the file paths.

As the user can't get into the Windows Explorer to delete the file `USB Storage`, the application wouldn't work after the batch file is started with no USB stick plugged in.

Somehow `IF EXIST "USB Storage"`is always false even if the USB Stick is plugged in and listed when using `dir`.

**Question**

How does the batch file need to look like to complete this task?

Comment: You need to supply your batch file, if we cannot see how it looks, we cannot show you how to make it look any different. You can add it to your original question using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46367757/edit) facility. Also why would you copy a file to a USB stick if it isn't plugged in?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: Have you tried `if exist "\USB Storage"` (note leading backslash)?

Comment: @CarstenHansen The leading backlashes do not seem to make any difference.

Comment: What about:
copy sourcefile "\USB Storage\*.**
This should fail if \USB Storage is not an existing folder
as an alternative you can try:
cd \Temp
cd \USB Storage
copy \pathtosource .
If \USB Storage is not there, file will be in \Temp and you can probably delete it.